# Trouble with async mongoose queries

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is the array that i get from my database, let's call it **product_list**

```
{
        "seller": "5cee0e69f67e171ac8ef14c7",
        "products": [...]
},
{
        "seller": "5d1c36910aec8934cefdda8e",
        "products": [...]
}
```

And i want to send the same array but transforming the seller field into the complete seller object. In the given example would be these ones.

```
{
        "_id": "5cee0e69f67e171ac8ef14c7",
        "name": "Will"
},
{
        "_id": "5d1c36910aec8934cefdda8e",
        "name" : "Jess"
}
```

So my desired output would be

```
{
        "seller": {
             "_id": "5cee0e69f67e171ac8ef14c7",
             "name": "Will"
        },
        "products": [...]
},
{
        "seller": {
             "_id": "5d1c36910aec8934cefdda8e",
             "name": "Jess"
        },
        "products": [...]
}
```

I tried the following

```
product_list.forEach(element => {
     User.findById(element.seller, function(err, user){
         element.seller = user;
     };
});
```

What i'm trying is to take all the seller ids from the **product_list** object, convert it to the complete object with User.findById, and return the updated product_list. But the problem is that i'm not to good with asynchronous code, and since the mongoose calls are callbacks when i return the object with `res.json(product_list)`, the mongoose query is not finished and i receive the object without the modification.

I tried promises and awaits but im not getting any result.

I hope you understand my explanation, and thank you very much.

Comment: If you have the seller field set as `ref` then it's pretty simple to use populate function. Let's say the product_list comes from Products collection, then `Products.find().populate('seller')`.

Comment: Thank you Molda, the populate function was very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome. Also in my opinion you shouldn't have accepted the aswer bellow since it doesn't really answer your question and it will not help others looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach, wrap User.findById and you can use the async / await pattern.

```
// Wrapper function for User.findById. We could use utils.promisify for this.
function getUserById(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        User.findById(id, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        })
    });
}

async function getSalesDetails(productList) {

    for(let product of productList) {
        let userDetails = await getUserById(product.seller);
        product.seller = userDetails; 
    }

    return productList;
}

async function testGetSalesDetails() {
    let productList = [{
        "seller": "5cee0e69f67e171ac8ef14c7",
        "products": [1,2,3]
    },{
        "seller": "5d1c36910aec8934cefdda8e",
        "products": [4,5,6]
    }];

    let productListWithSeller = await getSalesDetails(productList);
    console.info("Product list (with seller): ", productListWithSeller);
}

testGetSalesDetails();
```

You could also use utils.promisify to generate the getUserById function (it's very handy!), for example:

```
const getUserById = util.promisify(User.findById);
```

Comment: `Model.findById().exec()` returns a promise so the `getUserById` function doesn't seem to be needed. Also mongoose supports populating fields from another collection so something as simple as this `Products.find().populate('seller')` should do.